# How to stop running script by using different script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to write a script in which running scripts I want to stop and run different script.

Example:
Script 1 and Script 2 running in background.
Script 3 in which i want to stop script 1 and 2 and start executing script 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for terminating script1 and script2 try it like this

```
for i in `ps -ef | grep -w -E "script1|script2" | awk '{print $2}'`; do kill -9 $i; done
```

to run new script just

```
sh script4
```

Answer (score 2):

May be this could be a solution for you: Script 1 and Script 2 write their PIDs in a file, say scripts.pid. Script3 reads this file, retrieves PID values, sends kill -SIGINT $SCRIPT1_PID $SCRIPT2_PID and starts Script4.

Comment: I know I can kill the process by using PID but I cant always check the PID and close that process.

Answer (score 2):

In `script3`:

```
killall script1
killall script2
script4
```

Since this stops `script1` and `script2` by name, choose unusual names.

Note that it is best to kill a process with the default signal `SIGTERM`.  This allows the process to perform clean-up such as deleting temporary files and releasing resources.  By contrast, `SIGKILL` or `9` does not allow clean up and may leave a corrupted state behind.